# C# Serializable dynamic object

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dynamic

I have a requirement of communication between my WPF app and Silverlight app (Silverlight is hosted in a Web Browser control in my WPF application).

Basically, I have DataTable object in WPF and need this data in Silverlight (Columns are dynamic). Since DataTable is not available in silverlight, I cannot directly serialize/deserialize this DataTable.

I have looked at some lightweight DataTable class implementations (Example is [here](http://blog.effectlabs.com/post/2011/11/02/Lightweight-DataTable-for-Silverlight-applications.aspx), but they are not serializable.

Can somebody guide me,  what are my options to serialize/deserialize dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to convert to datatable,

```
  public class DataTable : IEnumerable
    {
         public DataTable(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> source)
        {
            if (source != null)
            {
                var firstItem = source.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstItem != null)
                {
                    foreach (var key in firstItem)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = key.Key, DataType = key.Value.GetType() });
                    }

                    foreach (var item in source)
                    {
                        var row = new DataRow();

                        foreach (var key in item)
                        {
                            row[key.Key] = key.Value;
                        }
                        Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<DataColumn> columns = null;
        public List<DataColumn> Columns
        {
            get
            {
                if (columns == null)
                {
                    columns = new List<DataColumn>();
                }

                return columns;
            }
        }

        List<DataRow> rows = null;
        public List<DataRow> Rows
        {
            get
            {
                if (rows == null)
                {
                    rows = new List<DataRow>();
                }

                return rows;
            }
        }

        public object NewRow()
        {
            if (queryable != null)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(queryable.ElementType);
            }

            return null;
        }

        #region IEnumerable Members

        IQueryable queryable = null;
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (queryable == null)
            {
                var type = ClassFactory.Instance.GetDynamicClass(this.Columns.Select(c => new DynamicProperty(c.ColumnName, c.DataType)));
                var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties().ToList();

                var list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
                foreach (var row in this.Rows)
                {
                    var item = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    propertyInfos.ForEach(p => p.SetValue(item, row[p.Name], null));

                    list.Add(item);
                }

                queryable = list.AsQueryable();
            }

            return queryable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        public IList ToList()
        {
            var enumerator = GetEnumerator();
            var list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(queryable.ElementType));
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                list.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    public class DataColumn
    {
        public DataColumn()
        {
            DataType = typeof(object);
        }

        public Type DataType { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataRow : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        //
    }
```

Comment: Where these classes? What reference I need to add:    var type = ClassFactory.Instance.GetDynamicClass(this.Columns.Select(c => new DynamicProperty(c.ColumnName, c.DataType)));

Comment: And How I make it serializable?

Comment: System.Linq.Dynamic.ClassFactory